# How to join a random rdd to another rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd

I have an `RDD` of strings (but could be anything really) that I would like to innerjoin with a `rdd` of random normals. I know this can be solved with a .zipWithIndex on both RDDs but this doesn't seem like it will scale well, is there a way to initialize a random `rdd` with data from another `RDD` or another method that would be faster? Here is what I've done with `.zipWithIndex`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.RandomRDDs
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val numExamples = 10 // number of rows in RDD 
val maNum   = 7
val commonStdDev   = 0.1 // common standard deviation 1/10, makes variance = 0.01
val normalVectorRDD = RandomRDDs.normalVectorRDD(sc, numRows = numExamples, numCols = maNum) 
val rescaledNormals = normalVectorRDD.map{myVec => myVec.toArray.map(x => x*commonStdDev)}
  .zipWithIndex
  .map{case (key,value) => (value,(key))} 

val otherRDD = sc.textFile(otherFilepath)
  .zipWithIndex
  .map{case (key,value) => (value,(key))} 

val joinedRDD = otherRDD.join(rescaledNormals).map{case(key,(other,dArray)) => (other,dArray)}
```

Comment: `zipWithIndex` is not an issue, but why would you join at all? If it is random, you can add vector in place with `map`.

Comment: @user6910411, I'm not sure I follow your comment but it does sound like an answer to my question. Maybe write this as an answer with the code and I'll see if it solves the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I wouldn't worry about `zipWithIndex`. While it requires additional actions it belongs to relatively cheap operations. `join` however is a different thing.

Since vector content doesn't depend on the value from the `otherRDD`, it makes more sense to generate it in place. All you have to do is to mimic `RandomRDDs` logic:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.random.StandardNormalGenerator 
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector  // or org.apache.spark.mllib

val vectorSize = 42
val stdDev = 0.1
val seed = scala.util.Random.nextLong  // Or set manually

// Define seeds for each partition
val random = new scala.util.Random(seed)
val seeds = (0 until otherRDD.getNumPartitions).map(
  i => i -> random.nextLong
).toMap

otherRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => {
  val generator = new StandardNormalGenerator()
  generator.setSeed(seeds(i))
  iter.map(x => 
    (x, new DenseVector(Array.fill(vectorSize)(generator.nextValue() * stdDev)))
  )
})
```